# Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to specified type 'Data'

Tags: swift, xcode, sms, xcode9-beta, messageui

I have the following code which takes a screenshot of the user's screen and allows them to send it to a friend as an attachment via SMS.

```
func sendSmsToFriend() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() && MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendAttachments() {

        let smsController = MFMessageComposeViewController()

        smsController.body = "Can you please tell me what colour this is?"
        let screenshotImageData: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshotImage!)!
        smsController.addAttachmentData(screenshotImageData, typeIdentifier: "data", filename: "screenshotImage.png")
        smsController.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.present(smsController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        print("User cannot send texts or attachments")
    }
}
```

The above works fine on a separate project, on the latest stable public release of Xcode.

I attempting to add the code to a project that will be running on the latest iOS (11.3 beta 2 I believe) and thus I'm using Xcode 9.3 Beta 2 (Released Feb 6th, 2018) to develop.

Is this a bug in the beta?

The error I am receiving is for the line:

`let screenshotImageData: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshotImage!)!` 
and subsequently on the line below too.

Getting:

`Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to specified type 'Data'`

Comment: clean derived data

Comment: Double (or triple) check that you don't define another `Data` type in your project. – Also note that the type annotion is not  necessary, i.e. `let screenshotImageData = ...` should compile fine.

Comment: also did you decide to switch to programming from politics ? :D

Comment: you can try  let screenshotImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshotImage!)!

Comment: @MartinR Worked! I can't believe I haven't tried this.. been a long day. You can post an answer if you'd like and I can mark it as solved

Comment: @Sh_Khan Worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to specified type 'Data'

indicates that there is another `Data` type defined in your application
or some included module, which conflicts with `struct Data` from the
Foundation framework. Here is a self-contained example to demonstrate
the problem:

```
import Foundation

struct Data { }

let d: Data = "abc".data(using: .utf8)!
// Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to specified type 'Data'
```

You can always prepend the module name to refer to a type from that module explicitly:

```
let screenshotImageData: Foundation.Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshotImage!)!
```

But actually you don't need the type annotation at all, with

```
let screenshotImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshotImage!)!
```

the type of `screenshotImageData` is inferred automatically from
the expression on the right-hand side (as `Foundation.Data`).

Of course it would be preferable to avoid such a ambiguity and not
define another `Data` type.

Comment: The latter `let screenshotImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenshotImage!)!` worked just fine. Thanks for your explanation!